# Convert day of year to Date in java

Tags: java, android

I got days in year in format 1-366

How do I convert them to actuall date like 12.12. etc.? + how it's with the 29.2.?

Thanks for answer!

Comment: You cannot do it without exact year, because of leap years.

Comment: So when I pick some year, I can set him to Calendar, then multiply number_of_days *24*60*60*1000 getting miliseconds and add it to calendar and get actual date?

Answer (score 4):

Seems easy to do with [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 366);
final Date date = new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

And if you want to offset a year for example:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
```

Comment: Be careful that this Calendar will contain its creation time - you may want to truncate the H/M/S fields to get rid of these.

Comment: Good point. Using `set()` for hours, minutes and seconds to `0` should do, right?

Comment: Yep, but I think there's a millisecond field too.  If you've got Apache commons-lang to hand, its DateUtils has a handy truncate method to do this.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. The `Year` and `LocalDate` classes in java.time handle this chore nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [joda-time-android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android):

```
MutableDateTime mutableDateTime = new MutableDateTime();
mutableDateTime.setYear(2012);
mutableDateTime.setDayOfYear(366);
```